# Moving a .zip file to the local folder

Tags: raspbian

I am trying to move a `.zip` file from the desktop of my Raspberry Pi to the local folder of the same Raspberry Pi.

I am using:

```
mv /home/pi/desktop/[filename.zip] /usr/local
```

This does not work.

Comment: What doesn't work? We're not magicians here, you need to specify *what* the actual problem is, not simply that you have one. My guess is that `/usr/local` is owned by the `root` user, and you're getting a `Permission denied` error. If so, run it with `sudo`: `sudo mv /home/pi/desktop/file.zip /usr/local`.

Comment: In addition to Steve's comment: Please remember to use basic capitalization and punctuation.

Comment: Why would you want to move the file to `/usr/local`?

Comment: In addition to `sudo` as @stevieb suggested, you probably want a `/` at the end of your command to place the file in the `local` *directory* . As it is, the command is trying to *rename* the zip file to `local` and then move it to the `/usr/` directory...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following:

```
mv /home/pi/desktop/[filename.zip] /usr/local/[filename.zip]
```

This website gives a few examples: [Computer hope](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/umv.htm). Also, as stated in the comments perhaps you should try typing:

```
mv /home/pi/desktop/filen
```

and try pressing the TAB key and let the terminal auto complete your file name.